# background property on div issue

Tags: html

I want this markup:

```
<div style="background:url('Untitled.jpg');height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
```

to behave as this markup:

```
<img src="untitled.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
```

The difference between the 2 is that the div doesn't fit the full image. It just crops it if the full image can't be fit inside the container. However img tag as we know shows full image. It scales down the image but shows it fully.

How can I achieve the same thing in div in background property of css? If possible, please do not suggest css3 because I need this to work on IE8. However it's fine. You can still suggest.

Comment: CSS2 doesn't resize images AFAIK; you'd need to use a third party tool like imageMagick to resize the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to reset the div completely:

```
<div style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: url('Untitled.jpg'); background-size: 100%; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, no. it's a CSS3 property. There's no other real way to stretch a background image via CSS alone. You'd have to do a `<div><img></div>` and do some positioning/z-indexing to fake it.

Answer (score 2):

If the background image is 50x50 pixels large, what you show should work fine. If the div doesn't stretch, try adding a `&nbsp;` to it.

If you need to *resize* the background image, you will indeed need to refer to CSS3 which has the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property.

Comment: I think what OP is looking for is for the image to downsize to 50x50. I could be wrong though, OP would have to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

background:url("untitled.png") 0 0 no-repeat; is required to declare the background property in full. or you can go background-image, background-repeat and background-position.

Comment: doesn't work with background:url("untitled.png") 0 0 no-repeat; I still see cropped image.

Comment: you have to add the size of the image. width:px; height:px;